# JMF: How to trigger event when player reaches certain time playing a video?

Tags: java, frameworks, media, jmf

How to code in Java (with Java Media Framework): When the player reaches a certain time playing a video clip (for example, reaching 3.124 minutes in reproduction time), it generates an event?

Answer (score 1):

The JMF [`Player`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Player.html) implements [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Clock.html) which in turn provides methods like:

- [`setStopTime(Time)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Clock.html#setStopTime%28javax.media.Time%29).  Add a listener to the player and listen for the stop event.
- [`getMediaNanoseconds()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Clock.html#getMediaNanoseconds%28%29). Start a Swing `Timer` to repeat every NN milliseconds.  Check the media time.  If it is beyond the time of interest, stop the timer & player.